# Mysql encoding not consistent

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I am portuguese and I am making a website that has vegetable names.

However, the encoding its not consistent. For example the word Agrião (watercress) sometimes comes out correctly but other times it comes out like AgriÃ£o.

As I refresh the page it picks one of them by random. Sometimes it's correct, sometimes it's not.

Comment: Looks like ISO 8859-1 displayed as UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a few factors:

1. MySQL columns / tables are not using the right encoding (UTF-8 is recommended)
2. The database session character set is not set properly (`SET NAMES utf8` [`mysql_set_charset()` for the deprecated API])
3. The page encoding is wrong (`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')`)

Comment: So does that mean that even tho it's in portuguese, everything should be in UTF-8?

Comment: @PCoelho Everything has to be consistent, that's the most important thing; whether it's UTF8 or ISO8859-1.

Comment: that solved it. Its strange why you actively need to change that. It should be defaulted at that. Thanks, you saved me time :)

Comment: UTF-8 takes more than one byte to represent characters 128 through 255, whereas single-byte encodings such as ISO 8859-1 only require one. So, it's a matter of efficiency while sacrificing flexibility.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yeah, it depends on how many languages you want to support; if you really only need one, UTF-8 might be overkill ... in our case we deal a lot with Japanese and Chinese languages, so that gets pretty rough without it ;-)